# Why the IS .. ELSE construct does not work in CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Why the is .. else construct does not work in CMD? It is in loop with EnableDelayedExpansion

```
IF ( !Delay! LSS !low_delay! ) ( SET priority=1 ) ELSE (
    IF ( !Delay! LSS !average_delay!) ( SET priority=2 ) ELSE (
      IF ( !Delay! LSS !high_delay! ) ( SET priority=3 ) ELSE (  SET priority=4 )  
))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is simply wrong.
Brackets are not allowed in the condition.
The brackets must be on the same line where the ELSE statement is.

```
IF !Delay! LSS !low_delay! ( 
  SET priority=1 
) ELSE (
    IF !Delay! LSS !average_delay! ( 
        SET priority=2 
    ) ELSE (
        IF !Delay! LSS !high_delay!  ( 
            SET priority=3 
        ) ELSE (  
            SET priority=4
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows batch scripting supports IF ELSE

You can do

```
if "%VAR%" == "OK" (goto dowork) else (if "%VAR%" == "MAYBE" (goto dowork) else (goto end))

:dowork

do work

:end
```

[External reference](http://commandwindows.com/batchfiles-branching.htm)